# How can I populate Angular Mat-Table with Observable

Tags: arrays, angular, observable, zero

I'm attempting to pull data from an AWS DynamoDB table and display it in an Angular Mat-Table. When I do this, the array created is returning a length of 0 even though there are 12 values in it. I believe this is preventing the Mat-Table from acting on the dataSource change and ultimately displaying the data.

Console Results

```
Observable {_isScalar: true, _subscribe: ƒ, value: Array(0)}
value: (12) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
_isScalar: true
_subscribe: ƒ (subscriber)
__proto__: Object
```

Component code

```
constructor(private dynamoService: DataDynamoService) {
    let dataSource: Observable<Record[]> = 
this.dynamoService.getAllRecords();
    console.log(dataSource);
}
```

Service function code

```
getAllRecords(): Observable<Record[]> {
  let dynDoc = {
  TableName: "records-table",
  };

  let retData: Record[] = [];
  Auth.currentCredentials()
    .then(credentials => {
      const dynamoDB = new DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
        credentials: Auth.essentialCredentials(credentials),
        region: 'us-east-1',
      });

      dynamoDB.scan(dynDoc).promise()
        .then(function(data){
          for(let record of data.Items){
            let rec = {
              value1: rec.value1,
              value2: rec.value2,
              value3: rec.value3,
              value4: rec.value4
            }
            retData.push(rec);
           }
        })
  })
  return of(retData);
}
```

I expect Array(12) for length, but am receiving 0

This is the service code that ultimately worked:

```
getAllRecords() {
  let dynDoc = {
    TableName: "my-table-name",
  };

  return Auth.currentCredentials()
    .then(credentials => {
      const dynamoDB = new DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
        credentials: Auth.essentialCredentials(credentials),
        region: 'us-east-1',
      });

      return dynamoDB.scan(dynDoc).promise()
        .then(data => {return of(data.Items);
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48415116/11451365

Comment: This code is using Cognito and Amplify.

Comment: `dynamoDB.scan(dynDoc)` - returns promise or observable ?

Comment: If you do not call .promise, it returns a request; or you can call .promise(). I have attempted both and receive the same results. The array within the promise returns an accurate length, but outside it does not. I believe the problem to be related to the fact that JavaScript doesn't wait and simply executes the case as is by design, my question is how do I work around this to get the desired data displaying in the MatTable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`retData` is filled after the promises are completed, but the function doesn't wait for it. So it will always be `[]`

Component code

```
_dataSource: any[] = []; <-- Data bound to mat-table

constructor(private dynamoService: DataDynamoService) {
    this.dynamoService.getAllRecords().then(data => { // <-- value on promise completion
      this._dataSource = data; // <-- set MatTable source to promise values
      console.log(data, this._dataSource);
    });
}
```

Service code

```
getAllRecords(): Promise<Record[]> { // <-- Return a promise, not observable
  let dynDoc = {
  TableName: "records-table",
  };

  let retData: Record[] = [];
  return Auth.currentCredentials() // <--- return outer promise
    .then(credentials => {
      const dynamoDB = new DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
        credentials: Auth.essentialCredentials(credentials),
        region: 'us-east-1',
      });

      return dynamoDB.scan(dynDoc).promise() // <-- return inner promise 
        .then(function(data){
          for(let record of data.Items){
            let rec = {
              value1: rec.value1,
              value2: rec.value2,
              value3: rec.value3,
              value4: rec.value4
            }
            retData.push(rec);
           }

          return retData; // <-- return the data outside the loop, still inside promise
        })
  })
}
```

Template code (for component)

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="_dataSource">

...

</mat-table>
```

If DynamoDB has the option to use observables I would switch to that though.

Comment: Understanding that the function doesn't wait, how would you make it so the MatTable respects that there is data to display?

Comment: ultimately the return at each level through the promise was the key.

Comment: Glad to hear it's working. Can you mark my answer as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `async` and `await` to wait promises.

```
async getAllRecords(): Observable<Record[]> {
    let dynDoc = {
        TableName: "records-table",
    };
    const credentials = await Auth.currentCredentials();

    const dynamoDB = new DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
        credentials: Auth.essentialCredentials(credentials),
        region: 'us-east-1',
    });

    let retData: Record[] = [];
    const data = await dynamoDB.scan(dynDoc).promise();
    for(let record of data.Items){
        let rec = {
        value1: rec.value1,
        value2: rec.value2,
        value3: rec.value3,
        value4: rec.value4
        }
        retData.push(rec);
    }

    return of(retData);
}
```

If `dynamoDB.scan(dynDoc)` returns Observable you can simply use

```
async getAllRecords(): Observable<Record[]> {
    let dynDoc = {
      TableName: "records-table",
    };

    const credentials = await Auth.currentCredentials();

    const dynamoDB = new DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
      credentials: Auth.essentialCredentials(credentials),
      region: 'us-east-1',
    });

    return dynamoDB.scan(dynDoc).pipe(
      map(data =>
        data.map(rec => ({
          value1: rec.value1,
          value2: rec.value2,
          value3: rec.value3,
          value4: rec.value4
        }))
      )
    );
}
```